# CSS: Add different style to one page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, styles

Note: I'm not fresh, but I am leaning towards a begginer.

The simple question is: How would I go about adding individual styles to different pages with only 1 style sheet?

Long version:
I have a general style sheet that sets all my website layouts. This determines my navigation bar, my header with logo, and generally everything.

I have been asked to add these tables to the website:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/flat-pricing-tables-for-twitter-bootstrap

Here's the theme that is being used on the website:
https://www.sktthemes.net/shop/cutsnstyle/

so I want the general layout of the website to stay the same, but have the table show up on the pricing page that is brought up.

I tried placing the style for the tables into the  portion of my pricing page html, but that didn't do anything. The page loaded with text, but was missing the tables completely.

I read about IDs and classes in order to specify layouts and style of pages. That being said, the style page from the table is this enormous thing with multiple IDs and classes already in it.

Can I put a classes in another class? My thought was "could I resolve this by setting each stylesheet as 2 different classes?". How would I also do this without breaking the general style for the theme of the website?
Can I put both styles in 1 style sheet? How would I go about setting these tables up?

(Apparently this has been marked as being a duplicate question. I took a look at the other topic, but I'm just very confused. I'm not a web designer and this task was assigned to me regardless. I'm just really trying to wrap my head around this. Any help would be appreciated)

Comment: What is the "free version of Wordpress"? WordPress is a free platform anyway.

Comment: They charge for a premium package, So the base word press is the free version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but for

> how would I go about adding a style to only one page

just inspect your page with Chrome DevTools and look at the `<body>` tag to see if there's any `class`es or `id`s that are unique to that page i.e.

```
<body class="post-234 someOtherClass etc">
    <div>Some stuff</div>
</body>
```

Then in your css:

```
.post-234 .div {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully I can explain it better:
I have a style sheet for the general theme of the website. This does all of the header, logo, and navigation. For the pricing page of the website, I was asked to add the table from here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/flat-pricing-tables-for-twitter-bootstrap
This has a style sheet of its own. I was wondering how I would go about adding this style sheet to my existing style sheet so it adds the tables only to my pricing page.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to insert the Pricing Table HTML but you don't have access to the HTML? Is that correct?

Comment: Actually, I do have the html.The problem is that the css is this huge style sheet, and I'm not sure how I need to incorporate it into my already existing css style sheet.

Comment: Just take all their styles and paste them into your stylesheet...
But if you're asking how to write CSS, perhaps you could Google some tutorials?

Comment: Yes, I've been googling CSS tutorials and that's allowed me to understand the general layout of CSS.
Would just throwing the two together actually work? For instance, they call for different background colors and font in body{}. Wouldn't these clash?

Comment: Yep just throw them together! They won't clash. Rarely you might see some of the earlier CSS getting overridden by later CSS, but if you're using `class`es and `id`s that won't usually happen.

Comment: That's actually interesting that you can throw CSS in like that. I actually got the tables to show up now. However, looks like the width is a bit messed up. How would I write the css to overwrite only some of the style?

Comment: Use Chrome DevTools to mess around with the CSS in real time. DevTools has an option to select any element on the page and "inspect" it's CSS (and tweak it)

Comment: Then after you figure out the answer in DevTools, just copy what you wrote and paste it into your CSS file

Comment: Thank you, you've been very helpful. I'll take a crack at it!

Answer (score 0):

Go look for your css file. Mostly, all the styles are put there if not inline style on the php file that you're using. 
And instead of using free version of wordpress, why not download the wordpress package at wordpress.org and to not complicate things, why not make your own theme from scratch or copy a theme code and modify it. I think it would be much easier than what you're doing..

THis is just a suggestion. I hope I can help. :)

Comment: If I were an actual web designer I'd write it all from scratch. But unfortunately, I am not. This is something that was thrown at me by my boss to do. Any help would be appreciated.